# What is the hot key to show the next command of the previous command in history in Linux/bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, command-history

In Windows cmd window, let's say I type and execute 40 commands like this:

```
echo 1[Enter]
echo 2[Enter]
echo 3[Enter]
...
echo 40[Enter]
```

If I decide to repeat the 40 commands again, in the same order, I do this:

- Press `[Up]` ---> prompt showing `echo 40`
- Press `[Up]` ---> prompt showing `echo 39`
- Repeat `[Up]` 37 times
- Press `[Up]` ---> prompt showing `echo 1`
- Press `[Enter]` ---> `echo 1` is executed
- Press `[Down]` ---> prompt showing `echo 2` <--- does not work in Linux/Bash
- Press `[Enter]` ---> `echo 2` is executed
- Press `[Down]` ---> prompt showing `echo 3`
- Press `[Enter]` ---> `echo 3` is executed
- Repeat `[Down][Enter]` 37 times to execute all the remaining commands
- If I press `[Down]` now, it cycles to `echo 1` again

In Linux/Bash, after finding in history and executing `echo 1`, pressing `[Down]` key does not give me anything. I have to press `[Up]` 40 times again to get `echo 2`. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ...
- Press `[Up]` ---> prompt showing `echo 1`
- Press `[Ctrl-O]` (that's the letter `o`, not zero) ---> `echo 1` is executed, prompt showing `echo 2`
- Press `[Ctrl-O]` ...

The hotkey can be changed in `.inputrc`, see `operate-and-get-next` in `readline`'s manual.

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation where changing the process may lead to a better solution.

You've tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) which is convenient. If you have 40 commands that you want to repeat, one option is to drop them into a shell script

```
fc -nl -40 >file
. file
```

Or perhaps you want to edit them first

```
fc -40 0
```

More excitement with `help fc`

Comment: There is also POSIX specification of the [fc utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html).